404 When accessing Simplesamlphp admin page
Need help getting past this error.Azure App Service running on PHP 8.2 and Linux.
Webserver is nginx. Followed the installation instructions here from the simpesamlphp.org page.
baseurlpath => 'https://mysimplesamlphp.azurewebsites.net/var/simplesamlphp/public/'
'secretsalt' => 'xxxxxxx' (masked)
'auth.adminpassword' => 'xxxxxxx' (masked)
Everything else default
When I try to hit the /public/admin page, I always get a 404 error. Any ideas?
As a test, I dropped a test php file in the same location and that loads fine. (edited)

yes to access the admin page you have to enable the admin module look into the config.php

search for 'module.enable' and enable admin like this
'module.enable' => [
    
   
    'admin' => true,
   
    
],

